# ¿Cómo conectar una aplicacion Java a una base de datos con servidor para diferentes empresas?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, servidor, arquitectura-de-software

Buenas, estoy haciendo un sistema de ventas el cuál será usado por algunos negocios y lo que quiero es hacer una base de datos que almacene toda la información de cada uno de los negocios que usen mi aplicación pero manteniendo la confidencialidad de cada negocio, es decir que yo como administrador de la base de datos de mi aplicación no vea la información guardada de cada negocio, no sé si me hago entender.
Por ejemplo, un negocio de ferretería usa mi aplicación y otro negocio aparte de abastos también usa mi aplicación pero no tiene nada que ver con el primer negocio, pero usan mi aplicación, entonces como haría para que todo esto se guarde si yo tengo un servidor en la web donde podría almacenar todo. No sé si tenga que hacer varias bases de datos o no, no sé muy bien sobre este tema. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varias alternativas para esto. Considera que no existe una respuesta correcta, y debes tomar la decisión basado en lo que se adecúe mejor a tu situación, requerimientos y presupuesto al corto y mediano plazo.

1. Tener una columna `idEmpresa` (o con un nombre similar) que te permita identificar a qué empresa le corresponde la información.

   Ventajas

   - Puedes mantener la información de múltiples empresas en las mismas tablas
   - Una sola base de datos por mantener y administrar. P.e. una sola estrategia de backup, un único punto para monitorear, una (no significa que haya solo un servidor).
   - Reduce cantidad de hardware a usar
   - Puedes escalar toda la base de datos a un coste muy bajo

   Contras (punto único de fallos)

   - En caso se produzca un problema en la base de datos, p.e. corrupción de información en una tabla, problemas de lentitud de red, entre otros, todos tus clientes sentirán el mismo efecto.
   - A pesar de necesitar poca infraestructura en un inicio, deberás planificar el escalamiento en cuanto vengan más clientes
   - Si se da mantenimiento a la base de datos y necesita que se detengan los trabajos o se reinicie el servidor, todos tus clientes no podrán trabajar o sentirán ciertos efectos de estos trabajos p.e. problemas de rendimiento.
2. Tener una base de datos por cada cliente. Crear una estrategia para identificar el nombre de la base de datos de cada cliente.

   Ventajas

   - Cada cliente tiene su información de manera independiente. Los problemas de cada cliente solo le afectan a él o ella, sin afectar a otros clientes.
   - Cada base de datos puede ir creciendo al ritmo del cliente. Esto es en caso de soportar diferentes versiones del producto para cada cliente. P.e. tu cliente A puede tener la base de datos y su esquema en la versión 1 mientras que un cliente B puede tener la base de datos y su esquema en la versión 2, habiendo pagado por el upgrade.
   - Al ejecutar trabajos de mantenimiento, solo se afecta a un cliente o un grupo de clientes en un momento, no se afectan todos los clientes.

   Contras

   - Requiere más hardware que la opción anterior. Esto significa que tendrás un mayor costo de infraestructura, lo cual es problemático para start ups y empresas pequeñas. Considerar también que el hardware, a diferencia de la opción anterior, va a ir creciendo mucho más rápido conforme aumenten tus clientes.
   - Conforme hayan más clientes, se necesitarán más administradores de bases de datos para mantener, administrar y supervisar todas las bases de datos. A diferencia del anterior, requiere más personal y mayor coordinación entre ellos.
   - Si ocurren problemas a nivel de hardware en tus servidores, todos los clientes se verán afectados.
3. Al brindar el producto, se entreguen los instaladores, los scripts de creación de base de datos y se delega todo el hardware de lado del cliente, de manera que te concentras en dar soporte y mantenimiento remoto (quizás no sea tu caso pero vale la pena mencionarlo como alternativa).

   Ventajas

   - El hardware y los problemas referidos a eso quedan de lado del cliente y no tuyo.
   - La administración de la base de datos también queda del lado del cliente.

   Contras

   - Al actualizar tu producto, es posible que tu cliente tenga dificultades para actualizar la versión de la base de datos o decida no actualizar en absoluto.
   - Es posible que puedan brindar tu producto a terceros y, posiblemente, lucrar con eso.

Cabe resaltar que, dependiendo de la estrategia que escojas, también depende cómo vas a diseñar la arquitectura de tu aplicación (sea Java o en cualquier LP).

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder! Tengo una pregunta: En el caso que quisiera hacer una base de datos por cada cliente, ¿Que debería hacer con respecto a lo del hosting? ¿Podría subir varias bases de datos a ese servidor web o necesito de algunos?

Comment: @Cristopher eso dependerá del servicio de hosting que uses. Tendrás que ver las limitaciones que tienes con ese proveedor.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo! Ha sido de mucha ayuda